# converting a Form to BCNF and 4NF

Tags: database, normalization

Im trying to convert this form into BCNF and 4NF.

So far this is what i have but i feel like its not right:

APPLICATION_INFO (SocialSecurity, LastName, FirstName, MiddleName, MaidenName, age)

APPLICATION_ADDRESS(SocialSecurity, Number,Street, City, State, Zip, HowLong, Telephone)

APPLICATION_POSITION(SocialSecurity, PositionApplied, SalaryDesired)

APPLICATION_DAYS_AVILABLE(SocialSecurity, NoPref, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thurs, Fri, Sat, Sun)

APPLICATION_EMPLOYMENT_DESIRED(SocialSecurity, FullTime, PartTime, FullTimeOrPartTime,AvilableToStart)

APPLICATION_EDUCATION_INFO(SocialSecurity, TypeOfSchool, NameOfSchool, Location, NumberOfYearsCompleted, Major/Degree)

APPLICATION_CRIME(SocialSecurity, Crime, Notes)

APPICATION_SIGN(SocialSecurity, Signnature, Date)

[image: Form]

Comment: You have to be in 3NF to proceed to 4NF. What you have is not in 3NF. An example of violating 1NF is: APPLICATION_DAYS_AVILABLE relation and the relation: APPLICATION_EMPLOYMENT_DESIRED

Comment: other issues: telephone in the address, howlong - which changes with the query date as a static value, location which = a full address, major/degree which repeats data values

Comment: can yall help me put it in 3NF? im still having a hard time with it

Answer (score 0):

You are listing SocialSecurity as the primary key in every table. This doesn't relate the tables one with another. Also, Application_Education_Info has repeating groups. You will have to fix this for the database to work properly.